# Is my JS accordion accessible?

Tags: javascript, accessibility, jquery-ui-accordion

This is a jQuery accordion that I put together:
http://jsfiddle.net/cutcopypaste/xAPSz/

I want to know whether it will work with screen-readers and other assistive technologies.

I know that with no javascript, everything will be expanded, which is totally fine.

I added a link hover effect to indicate that the headers are clickable, but I don't know what will happen with a screenreader... will all the content be visible at the outset? (which is ok) or will it be collapsed with no indication that the list items should be clicked on? What might be a good way of getting around this?

I was thinking of using js to add actual anchor tags around the header, to indicate it would be clickable (Rather than just the :hover style I'm using now) but wasn't sure if it would be worthwhile

Comment: go download JAWS and NVDA and test it

Comment: Read [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#accordion) and see what you did not implement.

Answer (score 2):

Screenreaders vary, but tend to only read what's visible on the screen. Since your accordion starts closed, it'd be good to replace the headings with links, or wrap the links around the heading text. That way they become clickable items for the screenreader, allowing users to either skip through the headings/links or open them up to get to the content.

Adding the links will make your accordion keyboard accessible too. Generally, if you want people to click on things to get a results, you're best off making them links and then styling them with CSS to look the way you want. It's less work than using other elements then adding back focus and activate functionality with scripting. You can tab to a link and activate it by pressing the enter key, which means that users with vision or mobility impairments can get at them easily.

Comment: One of my concerns was whether screen-readers adapt to changing content on a page well. Is that fairly standard capability these days? (most of my research was from varying dates and I couldn't get a good sense of what the landscape looks like these days)

Comment: Not really - but with accordions the content is there to begin with and then hidden from view, so they cope ok with that. JAWS and NVDA are the current popular screenreaders, and NVDA is free with some good tutorials online.

Comment: Whoops, hit enter too soon. Generally if you treat accessibility as part of your progressive enhancement, it makes it easier to develop for. Build your page for people without js/images/sight/mobility/large screens (usually fairly plain html/css with lots of anchor links), and then add your styles and scripting on top for the browsers than can handle it.